# How can I sign a bitcoin address that is on a paper wallet?

Tags: signature, paper-wallet, wallet-import

I have a bitcoin address that shows I held the BTC prior to December 2019.  I need to verify this but as the address refers to a paper wallet I don't seem to be able to do so.   If I move the coin to a hardware/software wallet I can verify BUT I will have created a new address that doesn't meet the criteria in that case.

Is there a way to sign a message with my paper based bitcoin address?  Or import the paper wallet into something that can sign messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import private key of bitcoin address (paper wallet) in [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#download)

[image: electrum-import-1]

[image: electrum-import-2]

[image: electrum-import-3]

[image: electrum-sign-msg-1]

[image: electrum-sign-msg-2]