# Can I spend from multiple wallets in Electrum (or somehow import/merge them)?

Tags: wallet, electrum

Is it possible, in Electrum, to merge wallets, and or do a transfer using multiple wallet keys?  I have some dust in a wallet and would like to get it out. I'm hoping I can easily incorporate it into another payment.

Given the sum of the dust, this is primarily a curiosity. I know it's possible in the protocol, but wondering whether there's a high level way, or even a command-line way.

Comment: The second screenshot in this answer : https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99819/ shows a window to specify all private keys to import in a new wallet on Electrum. Once you have all the addresses in a wallet, can easily create a transaction to use associated UTXOs in a transaction.

Answer (score -1):

You could export the private keys from all the wallets you wish to send from, save them to a file. (Wallet->Private keys->Export (to .csv) , open in Excel and copy the private_key column to a new file)

Build a new wallet with imported private keys on Electrum (File->New/Restore->[+] Import Bitcoin Addresses or private keys)

The new wallet would contain all addresses you wish to spend from